# Catching Probe Requests using monitor mode in Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I wanna catch probe requests of mobile devices that are not connected to a network using monitor mode on Raspberry pi 3. I am using Raspbian OS. I used "Wifite" command but it only shows the mac addresses of access points and not of the non connected mobile device. I am a beginner in networking and Raspberry pi. Kindly guide me which commands should I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking into [sniff-probes](https://github.com/brannondorsey/sniff-probes).

It switches WiFi channels every two seconds and captures incoming packets using `tcpdump`.